# Compressing scripts and styles and combining all js and styles references into single reference to optimize the sites performace

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, optimization, yui

I've multiple scripts and styles references in my asp site. When I observe my sites network instances it is doing 46 requests which is really too much and affecting my sites performance tremendously. Since I've multiple script and styles references in a page it is causing too much http calls. Now what I thinking of compressing all the scripts and styles in gzip and then combining multiple scripts in one scripts reference and multiple styles in one style reference.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/js1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/search/jsSerach.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/cust/jsCust.js"></script>
```

What I want when I move the testing code to production I would like to compress all three styles references and then combining them to single references like **masterStyle** similarly for all js references.

For achieving this I fond a nice tool [YUI tool](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/19/tools-for-concatenating-and-minifying-css-and-javascript-files-in-different-development-environments/) , but I am quite confused about how to use it and also thinks that I'd have to replace the references of the particular styles or scripts in the respective pages with the new combined references which I think may be some what risky.
Any one can suggest me how should I proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) nuget package which is designed to resolve this. For more info about how to apply this to ASP.NET Web form is provided in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx).

Note that provided solution will combine and minify scripts/css only in release mode. It is also quite flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [`Client Dependency Framework`](https://github.com/Shandem/ClientDependency) for this same goal with much success.
Since the main function of CDF is managing client dependancies, it will also provide the added value of allowing you to freely include client scripts in all you code and the CDF will include them only once, where needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/minify/
Try This For Combine all js and css minified

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution you use, you will want it to be automatically updated when you save one of the files that are part of it. This will save you a lot of time and frustration when creating and maintaining the website.

ASP.Net provides [bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) which combines and minifies your CSS and JS. This is definitely the preferred path for ASP.Net. To use bundling in Asp.Net, you just have to create your bundles (typically in global.asax.cs) like so...

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Whatever/YouWant.js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/File1.js",
    "~/Scripts/File2.js"));
```

And then write it to html like this...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Whatever/YouWant.js")
```

If debug is true in your web.config, it will write out each file, non-minified. If debug is false, then it will write out the path to the bundle along with a hash value of the files in the querystring and it will return a bundled and minified version of your code. The hash value allows you to cache the file in the client browser but if anything changes, the browser will request a new file.

The name of the bundle can be anything you want, but you should avoid naming it the same as an existing file or it won't work. I typically use ~/Bundles/Whatever.js to avoid this (assuming you don't have a folder called Bundles).

Another way to bundle your files is to use [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6). Web Essentials has a different way of handling bundling. You can right-click on the files you want to bundle and select Web Essentials -> Create XXX Bundle File. Personally I would probably avoid this feature since it is possible that Web Essentials might drop it since ASP.Net provides a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 0):

bundling and minification feature of vs 12 you can use also we have http://www.jsmini.com/ to minify javascript

Comment: I tried it. but it causes all my jquery to stop working. Anyways I am using http://jscompress.com/ to minify js and for bundling I am using 3rd party dll.